# gdb debugger multiple source files

Tags: c, gdb

When I attach gdb to a process that uses many source files, such as PHP, sometimes I want to set a breakpoint on line x of file y. How do I specify the file for gdb?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
b filename.c:XYZ
```

See [the documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

1. `gdb ./test.exe`  //test.exe is create by you program.
2. `b 117` //if only single file and line 117 is the function you want to run into
   `b filename.c:110` //filename:line NO
3. `r` //running the prog
4. `n`
5. `c` //continue
6. `s` //sign in the function you want to test
7. `until 1120` //if there is `for` branch and you want to skip the brand, given 1120 is after the `for` branch

You can shorten almost all commands in GDB up to the point where they remain unambiguous.